# How to change size of the UICollectionViewCell elements on the first appearance of a UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I need to build a `UICollectionView` with 9 cells, and elements of the first `UICollectionViewCell` should be bigger than the others. I've made it this way:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView 
cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
if (hero == YES) {
    CGRect cellbounds = cell.firstView.bounds;
    cellbounds.size = CGSizeMake(10, 10);
    cell.firstView.bounds = cellbounds;
}
else{

    CGRect cellbounds = cell.firstView.bounds;
    cellbounds.size = CGSizeMake(100, 100);
    cell.firstView.bounds = cellbounds;
}
```

The problem is that the first time I launch my app, all cells have the default size, and only after refreshing the CollectionViewCell required sizes are being applied (I've used `layoutIfNeeded`).

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
    [self.CollectionView layoutIfNeeded];
}
```

Tell me please, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try calling **[self.CollectionView reloadData];** in your controller's viewDidAppear.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement this delegate method, I'm supposing you are using a flowLayout.

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView 
                  layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout 
  sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Reference : [UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout_protocol/Reference/Reference.html)